# Link something between Model and View in MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, mvp

I am working on a class diagram for a Generic Graphical Editor (GGE), and in it I'm using the Model View Controller (MVC) pattern. The pattern is really great, but there is one thing that has me confused. I made a complete Selection class and tied it to the Model in MVC, but when this is the case, only one View (out of many in the Model) can have an active selection. If I tie the Selection class to the View, I break the rules of the pattern (logical "unseen" information in the view).

My question is: is there an effective way to link the Selection class "somewhere in the middle" between the View and the Model, so that the Model contains all the logical information, but all Views can have their own selection active at all times? The class diagram is of Java, if that means anything.

I found a derivative of MVC, Model View Presenter (MVP) pattern, but I don't see it being of any help. Am i missing something?

Thanks for the patience. :D

Comment: Additional information: I had an idea about adding serialization to the Select class so that every time a View is switched, if the previous View had selection, they would be exported and saved, and the View that is switched to would every time check if there is serialized selection for it. On exiting the program, all files that are selection serialized would be deleted. But this does not seem very effective, I would presume there is a much better way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is okay for the view to have state, especially if your "view" class is an MVC component (e.g. a JTable in Swing), so long as you put no logic in the view.  MVC and MVP are all about separating different types of code for modularity, testability, and understandability.  So long as you meet those criteria, you do not need to follow the "rules" dogmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually will move the Selection class to the View, and put the SelectedElements collection in there also, because I don't see any other way for the selection to be as effective.